# Converting bitmap-based KMLs to vector-based KMLs

Tags: svg, bitmap, kml

I have a bunch of kml files each of which contains references to one or more bitmaps (gifs) which have been rotated and georeferenced as image overlays in the kml file. The gifs were generated from CorelDraw.

So it struck me "Corel can export SVG as well as bitmaps. I wonder if it is possible to georeference the SVG output in a similar way in which the bitmaps are georeferenced. e.g. so where it now says
      
        http://www.rott.com/overlay/84.gif
      
      
        52.52497
        52.28735
        5.0677
        4.48675
        0.0

Change that to use an SVG equivalent like
      
        http://www.rott.com/overlay/84.svg
      
      
        52.52497
        52.28735
        5.0677
        4.48675
        0.0

Is that possible and if so, would the individual elements of the SVG file be georeference-able?

Or am I talking nonsense?